# Print AJAX Success Data?

Tags: java, javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with printing Ajax success data.

```
success: function(data){
    alert(need to print it here);
}
```

How it comes when I access

```
console.log(data.responseText);
{"success":false,"errors":{"text":["Some text.","some more text"]}}
```

How can I alert "Some text" or "some more text" now?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

alert data

```
 success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
```

write to div tag

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>

success: function(data){
        document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML += data; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a div to print the result like

```
<div id="res_div"></div>
```

You can access the contents by

```
console.log(data.responseText.errors.text);
```

You just try the following to print the content to that div

```
$("#res_div").text(data.responseText.errors.text);
```

Comment: thanks, but i get: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined "

Answer (score 1):

Just drill down the `data` object to the `errors.text` array and loop through them, like this:

```
$.each(data.responseText.errors.text, function(index, item) {
    alert(item);   
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but i get: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined "

Comment: well, still doesnt work :(  but thanks..  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined "